# Yii get all in clause returning recerd only by 1 key

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have criteria:

```
object(CDbCriteria)#186 (17) {
  ["select"]=&gt;
  string(1) "*"
  ["distinct"]=&gt;
  bool(false)
  ["condition"]=&gt;
  string(17) "t.type IN (:type)"
  ["params"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [":type"]=&gt;
    string(3) "2,3"
  }
  ["limit"]=&gt;
  string(2) "50"
  ["offset"]=&gt;
  int(0)
  ["order"]=&gt;
  string(17) "t.order_date DESC"
  ["group"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["join"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["having"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["with"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["alias"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["together"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["index"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["scopes"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=&gt;
  NULL
}
```

SQL query I thinks must look like that:

```
SQL query must be SELECT * FROM `transaction` WHERE type IN (2,3);

$model::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But problem is there, that I get records only where type is 2, but not get where is 3, why ?

Comment: please update your question with $criteria you are using

Comment: @Tomas does your model have a `defaultScope`? If so please include it. Also, for future reference, you should just add your declaration and initialization of `$criteria` instead of the dump.